# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении C++

Tags: c++, ооп, указатели, память, список

Посмотрел уже кучу тредов по поводу этой ошибки, но не могу понять, что не так у меня, ведь я,  вроде делаю все необходимые проверки на наличие пустых указателей.
В моей программе я создаю список. Соответственно, чтобы двигаться по элементам мои списка я использую привычную и стандартную конструкцию

```
Node *nx = head;
while(nx->next!=NULL){
nx = nx->next;
}
```

Однако, как только я пишу этот блок, то программа выдает ошибку во время исполнения, пишет, что обнаружено необработанное исключение и нарушение прав доступа. Однако, почему так происходит понять не могу - вроде все проверки на "NULL" у меня есть и обращения к пустому указателю не должно никак происходить.

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
#include "Triangle.h"
struct Node {
    Triangle tri;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
};
class List {
public:
    Node* head;
    List();
    void AddElem();
    //void DeleteElem(int i);
    //void GetElem(int i);
    //~List();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, List& d);
};
#endif
```

Вот ошибка происходит на строчке с while

```
List::List() {
    head = NULL;
}
void List::AddElem() {
    struct Node* elem = (Node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node)));
    std::cin >> elem->tri;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = elem;
    }
    /*else {
        Node* nx = head;
        //if (nx != NULL) {
            while (nx->next != NULL &&  nx!= NULL) { // здесь тоже ругается 
                nx = nx->next;
            }
            nx->next = elem;
            elem->prev = nx;
        
    }
    */
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, List& d) {
    if (d.head != NULL) {
        struct Node* nx = d.head;
        while (nx != NULL && nx->next != NULL) { // ошибка здесь 
            out << nx->tri << "\n";
            if (nx->next != NULL) {
                nx = nx->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "необработанное исключение и нарушение прав доступа" может происходить не только при разыменовании нулевого указателя.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Node *nx = head;
> while(nx->next!=NULL){
> nx = nx->next;
> }
> ```

Подозреваю, что не хватает проверки, что сам указатель NULL:

```
Node *nx = head;

if (nx)
  for(; nx->next; nx = nx->next)
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема найдена и решена - ошибка в том, что я не инициализировал указатели next и prev и они были не определены.
необходимо добавить

```
elem->next = NULL;
nx ->next = head->next
```